# Survival analysis but every observation is an event

Tags: survival, recurrent-events

I'm trying to formulate a problem using survival analysis to forecast the next occurrence, but every observation is an event, i.e you can't observe an event not happening. Each observation has a user ID, and I'm trying to see when the next event is going to happen for each user ID/

Would it make sense to use survival analysis in this case? And would there be a way to incorporate past observations, i.e the second most recent event in order to make a prediction?

UPDATE: As mentioned in the comment, this is a recurrent event situation. An individual can experience the event multiple times, and after each experience, the survival clock would reset back to 0, and the goal would be to predict the next event.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to tell us what is an event in your case? Survival analysis is about to waiting times to see an event, do you observe times?

Comment: It sounds like this is some type of recurrent event situation, with the same individual able to experience more than one event. There are several ways to model such data, but the best way depends on the underlying assumptions about the distribution of events. For example, do you think that `time =0` for the survival clock reset at each event? Please provide more information about the nature of your observations by editing the question. (Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.)